# Is it possible to acess a view object within a layout from a class which doesn't use the layout's contents?

Tags: android

I have a `RecyclerViewAdapter` class and 2 layout files, `choose_language.xml` and `recyclerview_list_item.xml`.
The `choose_language` layout contains the declaration of the recycler view object and 2 other views, a text view and a button.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chooseLanguageTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chooseYourLanguage"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okButton"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background_3"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ok"/>
```

The Recycler View dynamically creates Radio Buttons

```
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="English"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

I want to access the TextView and Button from my RecyclerViewAdapter class so that as soon as a radio button(containing the language name) is clicked, the text of the 2 views should be modified in that language accordingly.

The method where i want this to happen

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        RadioButton radioButton;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            radioButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);

            radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    lastSelectedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    langCodeIndex = 0;

                    for(String lang:langOptions){
                        if(lang.equals(radioButton.getText().toString()))
                            break;
                        langCodeIndex++;
                    }

                    setLocale(langCode[langCodeIndex],_context);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private static void setLocale(String preferredLanguage, Context context){
        Locale locale = new Locale(preferredLanguage);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        if(!preferredLanguage.equals(""))
        onConfigurationChanged(configuration);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("LanguageSettings",context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("PreferredLang",preferredLanguage);
        editor.apply();

    }

@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        //Want to access the choose language and okButton views so that i can instantaneously display the changes made to the language like this

        chooseLanguage.setText(R.string.chooseYourLanguage);
        okButton.setText(R.string.ok);
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }
```

The langOptions and langCode are as follows:

```
String[] langOptions = {"English","हिंदी","ગુજરતી","मराठी","বাঙালি","ਪੰਜਾਬੀ","ಕನ್ನಡ","தமிழ்","తెలుగు"};
String[] langCode = {"en","hi","gu","mr","bn","pa","kn","ta","te"};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `interface` for this for such interaction.

1. Create an interface :

   ```
   public interface IMethodCaller {
    void yourDesiredMethod();
   }
   ```
2. Implement this interface in your Activity(which has refernce of the TextView & Button), call change language method()
3. Create a parameter `Context` in your Adapter's constructor.

   ```
   public AdapterName(Context context, ...) {

     this.mContext = context;

     //.. other code

   }
   ```
4. Write below code inside `onClick()` in your Adapter :

   ```
   if (mContext instanceof YourActivityName) {

     ((YourActivityName)mContext).yourDesiredMethod();

   }
   ```
5. Change text of the TextView & Button from `yourDesiredMethod()` method in `Activity`.

Refer https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/gestures-animations-flexible-uis/communicating-between-fragments-activities for an example.

Feel free to ask for any further clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me . I am a beginner, hence inquisitive

Answer (score 0):

**NO**. You cannot access UI element from a class which doesn't have reference to it. UI components in the layouts bind to classes in your app programmatically or by using any `data binding mechanism`. These classes hold reference to these UI elements. Hence, **the approach you are trying is incorrect**. 
You can achieve the same in 2 ways : **`Callback`** or **`Local Broadcast Manager`**.

1 - `Callbacks` can be created using interfaces. So on click of radio button you can trigger the callback which will perform your desired operation. You can pass your required data in the arguments of your callback.

2 - `Local Broadcast Manager` can be used which will be triggered on click of the radio button. Then inside `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` you can perform you desired operation. Pass data using intent when you trigger `LocalBroadcast`. In your case, you will trigger `broadcast` from `Adapter` class and it'll be received inside your `Fragment` or `Activity` class.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. I am new to Android Studio, hence i didn't know whether it is possible directly or not